# Proof for Fibonacci Number Equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

The question I'm facing is as follows:

$$ \text{For any $n \geq 1,$ } {F_{n+1}^2} - {F_{n-1}^2} = F_{2n} $$ and I have the following identity I can use to help prove: $$ {F_{n}^2} + {F_{n-1}^2} = F_{2n-1} $$

Comment: Umm... what's the problem?  Let $n \to n-1$.

Answer (score 0):

As @DavidG.Stork hints,$$F_{n+1}^2-F_{n-1}^2=(F_{n+1}^2+F_n^2)-(F_n^2+F_{n-1}^2)=\cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

This follows from the hint, identity and the Fibonacci recurrence: $F_{n+1}^2 + F_n^2 = F_{2n + 1}$, $F_n^2 +  F_{n-1}^2 = F_{2n - 1}$ from the identity and $F_{2n} = F_{2n +1} - F_{2n -1}$.