# Finding a Proof For a Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

I saw the question asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3870021/proof-for-fibonacci-number-equation), but am struggling to understand how exactly what is meant by the response. I "moved" all of the terms down such that it became $$ F_{n}^2 - {F_{n-2}^2} = F_{2n} $$ but am unsure of where to go. I also attempted to sub $$F_{n-1}^2 = F_{2n-1} - F_{n}^2 $$ from the identity into the equation and got $$ {F_{n+1}^2} - (F_{2n-1} - F_{n}^2) = F_{2n} $$ which you eventually get down to $$F_{n+1}^2 = F_{2n} $$. But I can't see any way to either turn the identity into the proofing equation or turn the proofing equation into the identity. Any help would be great.

Comment: I think you should be following up on J.G.'s answer rather than David G. Stork's comment. Do you see why J.G.'s equation is true? Do you see any way to use the identity you have to simplify the two expressions in parentheses?

Comment: @WillOrrick I just saw DavidW's comment and was not aware of the fact that {F_n+1}^2+{F_n}^2 = F_{2n+1} instead of F_{2n}. Why is it not the latter as the rul;e for Fibonacci rules is that F_{n} = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2} ?

Comment: Replace $n$ in $F_n^2+F_{n-1}^2=F_{2n-1}$ with $n+1$. This gives $F_{n+1}^2+F_{(n+1)-1}^2=F_{2(n+1)-1}$. Then simplify.

Comment: Also, two of the equations in this post are incorrect: $F_n^2-F_{n-2}^2=F_{2n}$ is invalid (the right side should be $F_{2n-2}$) and $F_{n+1}^2=F_{2n}$ is wrong since it incorrectly implies that every Fibonacci number of even index is a perfect square.